# Find String with regexp

Tags: javascript

How can I find if a string starts with `[` and ends with `]` in JavaScript?

```
var str = '[["a" , "b"]]';
```

And is there any way to identify if the above string is typeof array of array?

Comment: I imagine that you have this returned from AJAX, as otherwise you'd just be able to use this string without the outer quotes. If this is the case, have you thought of using JSON?

Comment: Your rule is vague. What should be the output? `[["a" , "b"]`, `[["a" , "b"]]`, `["a" , "b"]]` or `["a" , "b"]`?

Comment: @sp00m I think we can rule out the unbalanced ones.

Comment: A string is always typeof string - you have to convert it to a real js-object to test it's type.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '[["a" , "b"]]';

str.match(/^\[.*\]$/);
```

matches strings starting (`^`) with a `[` and ending `$` with a `]`. Since the brackets are control-characters, you have to escape them. In between, there can be an arbitrary amount of characters `.*`

For what you are trying to to, regex is not suitable. Instead of that, parse the string:

```
try{
    var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    alert(typeof obj);
} catch (e) {
   alert("No valid JSON!");
}
```

Now `obj` is a real JavaScript object, where you can call `typeof` on.

Comment: I guess the `.*` should be `[^\[]*?`

Comment: @Anirudha no, i meant it exactly as it stands. Your regex actually would not match the given string. If you are really excluding the brackets, you have to exclude `]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

To find out, whether your object is an array, you might try this:

```
if (str.match(/^\[.*\]$/)) {
    var test = JSON.parse(str);
    // Note, that you COULD use 'eval' here, but JSON.parse is the better solution.
    // Check out this post: http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval

    if (test.constructor == Array) {
        alert("I'm an array!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Christoph: You MAY doesn't sound like a recommendation, does it? Whatever, I change the post accordingly.

Comment: It's an unexperienced Javascript user - why introducing bad habits when it's not necessary?

Comment: I think, the modified post clarifies this. Plus it gives more information about WHY you shouldn't do that (to avoid such errors in future). But on the other hand, you're right, I probably shouldn't have even mentioned the eval...